# MySQL Stored procedure with parameters declared from Select

Tags: mysql, opencart

I'm trying to create MySQL stored procedure for my Opencart store.  In order for a product to be visible, it must be in 3 tables

1. oc_product
2. oc_product_description
3. oc_product_to_store

So I insert into the first table, collect the ID & insert into the following tables with that ID.

If I were to do it outside of a stored procedure, all of the individual steps DO work.  However once I put them all together (below) I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @vProductID = (SELECT `product_id` FROM `oc_product` WHERE UPC='1234567890' ' at line 9
```

My Stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`myname`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `uspAddNewProduct`(IN `vModel` VARCHAR(500), IN `vSKU` VARCHAR(500), IN `vUPC` VARCHAR(500), IN `vMPN` VARCHAR(500), IN `vQTY` INT(10), IN `vPrice` DECIMAL(18,2), IN `vProductID` INT, IN `vProductName` VARCHAR(500), IN `vProductDescription` VARCHAR(500), IN `vMetaTitle` VARCHAR(500))


-- INSERTS THE BULK OF THE DATA INTO THE MAIN PRODUCT TABLE
INSERT INTO `oc_product` (`model`, `sku`, `upc`, `mpn`, `location`, `quantity`, `stock_status_id`, `image`, `shipping`, `price`, `tax_class_id`,`date_available`, `minimum`, `status`, `date_added`, `date_modified`, `weight_class_id`)
VALUES (vModel,vSKU,vUPC,vMPN,'NYC',vQTY,'5','catalog/product/' + vUPC + '.jpg','1',vPrice,'9',NOW(),'1','1',NOW(),NOW(),'1')

-- SELECTS THE RECENTLY CREATED PRODUCT ID
SET @vProductID = (SELECT `product_id` FROM `oc_product` WHERE UPC='1234567890' ORDER BY   `product_id` DESC LIMIT 1)

-- INSERTS INTO A DESCRIPTION TABLE (BASED ON THE PID ABOVE)
INSERT INTO `oc_product_description` (`product_id`, `language_id`, `name`, `description`, `meta_title`)
VALUES (vProductID, '1', vProductName, vProductDescription, vMetaTitle)

-- ASSOCIATES THE PRODUCT WITH THE MAIN STORE (BASED ON THE PID ABOVE)
INSERT INTO  `oc_product_to_store` (`product_id`, `store_id`) VALUES (vProductID, '1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with the variable `vProductID`, is a stored procedure parameter, but is then redefined in the `SET`. Remember that `vProductID` and `@vProductID` are different variables.

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE DEFINER=`myname`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `uspAddNewProduct`(
  IN `vModel` VARCHAR(500),
  IN `vSKU` VARCHAR(500),
  IN `vUPC` VARCHAR(500),
  IN `vMPN` VARCHAR(500),
  IN `vQTY` INT(10),
  IN `vPrice` DECIMAL(18,2),
  IN `vProductID` INT,
  IN `vProductName` VARCHAR(500),
  IN `vProductDescription` VARCHAR(500),
  IN `vMetaTitle` VARCHAR(500)
)
BEGIN
  -- INSERTS THE BULK OF THE DATA INTO THE MAIN PRODUCT TABLE
  INSERT INTO `oc_product` (
    `model`,
    `sku`,
    `upc`,
    `mpn`,
    `location`,
    `quantity`,
    `stock_status_id`,
    `image`,
    `shipping`,
    `price`,
    `tax_class_id`,
    `date_available`,
    `minimum`,
    `status`,
    `date_added`,
    `date_modified`,
    `weight_class_id`
  ) VALUES (
    `vModel`,
    `vSKU`,
    `vUPC`,
    `vMPN`,
    'NYC',
    `vQTY`,
    '5',
    CONCAT('catalog/product/', `vUPC`, '.jpg'),
    '1',
    `vPrice`,
    '9',
    NOW(),
    '1',
    '1',
    NOW(),
    NOW(),
    '1'
  );

  -- SELECTS THE RECENTLY CREATED PRODUCT ID
  -- SET @vProductID = (SELECT `product_id` FROM `oc_product` WHERE UPC='1234567890' ORDER BY   `product_id` DESC LIMIT 1)
  SET `vProductID` := (
              SELECT `product_id`
              FROM `oc_product`
              WHERE `UPC` = '1234567890'
              ORDER BY `product_id` DESC LIMIT 1
  );

  -- INSERTS INTO A DESCRIPTION TABLE (BASED ON THE PID ABOVE)
  INSERT INTO `oc_product_description` (
    `product_id`,
    `language_id`,
    `name`, `description`,
    `meta_title`
  ) VALUES (
    `vProductID`,
    '1',
    `vProductName`,
    `vProductDescription`,
    `vMetaTitle`
  );

  -- ASSOCIATES THE PRODUCT WITH THE MAIN STORE (BASED ON THE PID ABOVE)
  INSERT INTO `oc_product_to_store` (
    `product_id`,
    `store_id`
  ) VALUES (
    `vProductID`,
    '1'
  );
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use either of the below

```
SET vProductID = (SELECT `product_id` 
FROM `oc_product` 
WHERE UPC='1234567890' 
ORDER BY `product_id` DESC LIMIT 1)
```

or

```
SELECT `product_id` into vProductID 
FROM `oc_product` 
WHERE UPC='1234567890' 
ORDER BY `product_id` DESC LIMIT 1
```